# CCS C compiler , command line instructions

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded

Anybody here can please say what are the commands to compile and run C files from compile line.Like

```
GCC -o op_filename ipfilename.c  in gcc compiler.
```

same way are there any specific commands of CCSC. 
 I work on regular c but am really new to Embedded C. So please help me.

Comment: Is this Texas Instruments' gcc (I'm guessing CCS stands for Code Composer Studio)? If it is, there should be official compiler documentation from TI, some of those spru, spra, etc pdf documents. Look 'em up.

Comment: please give more info about ccs c compiler

Comment: [Link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ccstudio%20manual&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fcs%2Facademic%2Fclass%2F15745-s05%2Fwww%2Fc6xref%2Fspru509e.pdf&ei=EDplUa3_E8rirAfp9IG4DA&usg=AFQjCNFGqcyYWlyo7uyg1QfdpRbfWZDAew&bvm=bv.44990110,d.bmk&cad=rja) section `4.5.3`. by the way why are you not using the IDE?

Comment: @Koushik:  The ambiguity is between whether he is using TI Code Composer Studio, or a PIC compiler from CCS Inc.  The latter seems more likely, but the answer is indeed to read the documentation in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The rather obvious suggestion perhaps is to read the manual!?

For [dsPIC/PIC24](http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/PCDReferenceManual.pdf).
For [PICs with 12, 14, or 16 bit op-code interuction sets](http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf).

In both cases the section "Invoking the Command Line Compiler" directly addresses your question.

As you can see you need to be more specific about what compiler you are using, especially since "CCS" may also refer to [Code Composer Studio](http://www.ti.com/tool/ccstudio) rather than [CCS Inc](http://www.ccsinfo.com/).  You should also specify the compiler version you are using in order to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best suggestion will be to read the manual. In that it'll be clearly explained.

In command line go to compiler location for eg Texas Instruments\ccsv4\tools\compiler\tms470\bin.  Compiler  in case of tms470 is cl470.exe .

For example, if you want to compile two files named symtab.c and file.c, assemble a third file named
seek.asm, and link to create an executable program called myprogram.out, you will enter:
cl470 symtab.c file.c seek.asm --run_linker --library=lnk.cmd
--library=rts16.lib --output_file=myprogram.out